# Restrict countries for shipping in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

I have multi store website in magento. In one of my website I want to restrict the countries that I can make shipping. But the payment can be received from anywhere of the world. I have tried

> system --> configuration --> web --> general

And

> system --> configuration --> shipping method --> specify country

but the problem is that in checkout page, I want to show all countries name in the dropdown list of billing information and I want to show only a specific country, eg: India in the dropdown list of shipping information. Is there any way to do so? Any help would be great full... Thank you.

Comment: switch hints to on. You will get block name. modify that block code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Class : abstract class

```
Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
```

**public function getCountryHtmlSelect($type)**

```
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'[country_id]')
            ->setId($type.':country_id')
            ->setTitle(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Country'))
            ->setClass('validate-select')
            ->setValue($countryId)
            ->setOptions($this->getCountryOptions());
```

So `setOptions($this->getCountryOptions()`  is responsible for that `drop down list of shipping countries.`
Here you place is $type is equal to shipping then call `$this->getShippingCountryOptions()`
follow this by writing your own code for this function refering to  function `getCountryOptions()` code.

Note : Do not touch core files. This is just a guideline.